# Help using uint32_t? Trying to feed arduino serial from raspberry pi. Any help is very very much appreciated

Tags: programming, c++

So I don't know C so I'm just trying to get some very very basic code running on my arduino to send it commands over serial.

I'm feeding serial into buf

irsend.sendNEC(0x210704FB, 32)

this works but I need to read from buf instead of hardcoding for one code.

irsend.sendNEC(buf, 32) won't compile but irsend.sendNEC((uint32_t) buf, 32) will. It just doesn't do anything.

When I use

serial.print((uint32_t) buf, 32);

it prints just seemingly random letters?

I'm trying to just feed it a serial code with a language I know a little better. I can send the hex code over serial with python but I don't know the first thing about C. I don't understand why I can't just feed it a variable and have it read it as is.
here's my code

```
#include <IRremote.h>

char buf[80];

int readline(int readch, char *buffer, int len) {
  static int pos = 0;
  int rpos;

  if (readch > 0) {
    switch (readch) {
      case '\r': // Ignore CR
        break;
      case '\n': // Return on new-line
        rpos = pos;
        pos = 0; // Reset position index ready for next time
        return rpos;
      default:
        if (pos < len-1) {
          buffer[pos++] = readch;
          buffer[pos] = 0;
        }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

IRsend irsend;

void loop() {
  if (readline(Serial.read(), buf, 80) > 0) {
    //tried to set up code to show what the arduino received and tried ways to send
    //Serial.print("You entered: >");
    //Serial.print(buf);
    //Serial.println("<");
    //doesn't seem to do anything irsend.sendNEC((uint32_t) buf, 32);
    //works but only for this one button irsend.sendNEC(0x210704FB, 32);
    //want to use irsend.sendNEC(buf, 32);
    //me trying to figure out what irsend is being fed through buf Serial.print((uint32_t) buf, 32);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `buf`? The first two `sendNEC` in your question are identical but you say one compiles and one doesn't - probably a wrong copy/paste. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: `serial.print(...., 32)`. "32" [is not a valid second parameter for the `serial.print()` function](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/) when printing an integer value. Just leave it out or replace it with either "BIN", "DEC", "OCT" or "HEX". BTW, what is your question exactly?

Comment: I updated my post yesterday to add some clarity and show my entire code instead of just the specific function I was having a problem with. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue for me, but this is my solution.

Mapping beween python struct (packed data) and arduino struct is as follows:

```
Python              Arduino
?                   boolean
i                   int32_t or uint32_t 
f                   float
```

Arduino Code:

```
// The struct we want to send over the serial connection
struct Data {
  int32_t timer;
  float value2;
  uint32_t sensor1;
  uint32_t datasize;  
};
 Data data;
void setup() {
  // Initialize the serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // Create an instance of the Data struct
 
  data.timer = micros();
  data.value2 = 3.14;
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  data.sensor1 = analogRead(A0);
  

  // Calculate the size of the struct in bytes
  size_t size = sizeof(data);
  data.datasize = size; 
  // Allocate a buffer for the packed data
  uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);

  // Pack the data into the buffer
  memcpy(buf, &data, size);

  // Send the packed data over the serial connection
  Serial.write(buf, size);

  // Free the buffer
  free(buf);

  // Wait before sending the data again
  delay(10);
  
}
```

Python Code:

```
#
# read struct from arduino / sample code above
#

import serial
import struct

# Open the serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)

# The struct we expect to receive from the Arduino
#struct Data {
#  int32_t value1;
#  float value2;
#  uint32_t value3;
#}
expFormat = "i f i i"         # Format to match arduino struct
structDataLength = struct.calcsize(expFormat)
print(structDataLength)       # RESULT IS 12

while True:
# Read the data from the serial port
# We read until we have received all the bytes for the struct
    
    data = b''
    while len(data) < structDataLength:
        data += ser.read(structDataLength - len(data))
    # Unpack the data into an instance of the Data struct
    val = struct.unpack('i f i i', data)

# Print the values
    print(val)

# Close the serial port
ser.close()
```